# Why ajax doesn't send my JS variable to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send JS variables to a PHP script (which is included in the page I try to make ajax work)

> index.php

```
include 'PHP/display.php';
<button id="click" onclick="show();">Click !</button>

<script>
  function show(){
    var str = "Yes";
    $.ajax({
      method : 'post',
      url : 'PHP/display.php',
      data: {
        str : str
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

> display.php

```
<?php
  echo isset($_POST['str']) ? $_POST['str'] : "No";
?>
```

This keeps displaying "No", but the console shows me the "Yes" I want

This code is my first try with ajax, that's why I try to keep it simple, but it doesn't work.

I've been looking for hours on StackOverflow and not one solution works for me.

Maybe i'm missing something, please help me :(

Comment: use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`, because with ajax you are sending the data with the `POST` method

Comment: I think you meant to use `$_POST`

Comment: Is that button in  a form? If it's in a form then the page is likely reloading due to form default submit process

Comment: I tried with POST, its the same problem and the button isn't in a form

Comment: So you are seeing the "No" in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: No, the no is only displayed by php, because POST['str'] is considered non-set, but Yes is displayed in console

Comment: Well then the ajax is working. If you try opening that page in browser the post data isn't there. Is that what you are doing to see the No?

Comment: Yes, I open my page on my browser, i click my button (because my function is called onclick on my button) but nothing happens

Comment: You don't want to include that echo in index.php. Perhaps you should make a separate file for the ajax to send to

Comment: the problem is in the `include` line, because the PHP code is executing before being called with JavaScript, that's why it will always show no, because `$_POST['str']` is empty

Comment: That makes sense, if I put my PHP code in separate file (not incuded), how do I echo this "Yes" on my index page ?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding that the data sent by ajax will be available inside the index by including the same file. It doesn't work that way. Each time the file is run it expects to have that data as input. Each instance knows nothing about the last instance when it ran

Comment: I think i get that, but now I want to send my JS variable to a separate PHP script, then display this variable from this php script, without reloading or changing page. Of course the actual purpose is bad, but when i'll make it work, i'll use it in a useful way.

Comment: I got variables in my JS, these depends on what user will do on page (select a date on a calendar), I want to send this date to a php script that will display all the events of this date, from my database (that's why I need my variables in PHP)

Comment: Well your choices would be to put data in the url and read it with $_GET or store it on server in session or database. Not enough known to help much more

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can see the `url` property of the ajax call like the php `include`, but the difference is that it will be executed until you click on the button. PHP will be able to receive the content of `data`

You can use jQuery's [text](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method to assign the response to the call to the paragraph as text.

```js
function show() {
  var str = "Yes";
  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'display.php',
    data: {
      str: str
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#response').text(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<p id="response"></p>
```

`display.php`

```php
<?php
echo isset($_POST['str']) ? $_POST['str'] : "No";
```

Comment: I made something like this a few hours ago, it's fine but I can't figure how to transform it to display the events that are the same date (JS variable) I sent with ajax from my database

Comment: It's alright, I got it, instead of including my php file into my div (where i want to display my things) I just put the id of this div in the jquery selector : $.(id).text(data) and its working ! I didn't notice that data represents what the php script returned